# Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to join two columns from two tables to generate unique id.Max column value of one column with row number of another table.

```
select (MAX(S.m_id))from MPPO S;
select row_number() OVER(ORDER BY G.a,G.r,G.f1,STG.filler2,G.n_p,G.fe,G.se) 
FROM mmp G
LEFT OUTER JOIN mppo S
ON TRIM(G.pc) = S.pc;
```

But when combine these two query as below:

```
select (MAX(S.m_id))+ row_number() OVER(ORDER BY G.a,G.r,G.f1,STG.filler2,G.n_p,G.fe,G.se) 
FROM mmp G LEFT OUTER JOIN mppo S
ON TRIM(G.pc) = S.pc;
```

I get the following error:

```
SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group
must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error:
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select id from each tables separately then join output:

```
select concat(t.id,'',t1.id) from (select MAX(S.m_id) as id from MPPO s) t join (
select row_number() OVER(ORDER BY G.a,G.r,G.f1,STG.filler2,G.n_p,G.fe,G.se)  as id
FROM mmp G
LEFT OUTER JOIN mppo S
ON TRIM(G.pc) = S.pc) t1 on 1=1
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issue in Hive. I wanted to share my experience just in case someone is having similar issue

select statement had following partition clause

```
COUNT () OVER (PARTITION BY mc.source_well_key, mc.report_dt order by mc.report_dt ) AS r_number
```

The correct syntax is

```
replace count() with count(1) or count(*)
```